# How to take the Calendar date and time as String?

Tags: ios, swift

I added calendar in my app, it shows the months along with the time. Through this i can select the date and time , but i have no idea how to take this date and time as a string and use it in my code. This i my code:

```
 dateTimePicker.preferredDatePickerStyle = .compact
 dateTimePicker.datePickerMode = .dateAndTime
```

Here is an Image of the calendar from my app:
[image]

Comment: What do you want to with the string? Most operations are done with Date, except displaying the date.

Comment: i have to pass the date and time to record it